# Is there a way to obtain device screen width and height using Codename One?

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I am looking to obtain screen dimensions of a device either under Codename One or basic Java.

The previous approach that I had used involved imports from java.awt package, but however upon code compiling my code, a semantic error is obtained concerning the java.awt package which is stated that it does not exist

Then concerning Codename One, I am failing to locate the API that I should use in obtaining device width and height.

Comment: Please don't ask for urgency of volunteers here, thanks.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the answer marked, the answer is to use: Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth() Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight()

Comment: @Chen: are both of the below answers incorrect?

Comment: @halfer yes, they are both incorrect. the answers below shows how to get screen dimensions with the native android API, he is asking how to get this in a codenameone app

Comment: Thanks @Chen, voting to reopen. Let us know if you find a duplicate though.

Comment: I vote to reopen, too. If there's a better way (I couldn't find any button for it) please let me know.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz Two years later, we managed reopening.

Answer (score 1):

This works :

```
 Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight();
 Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();
```

The lines are probably self explanatory.